# unable to install datamapper in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-datamapper

I've done all the required setting but I do not know where I am going wrong. Can anybody please help me out . Its really uregent.
 Following is the error I am getting when I run my project.

**Unable to load the requested file: helpers/datamapper_helper.php**

Please somebody help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It appears `datamapper_helper.php` isn't in the `/helpers` directory. It's not a file that's included in the library by default; the closest thing I found was http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/205637/P270

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I got it done. I got a proper DATAMAPPER File and loaded it on CODEIGNITER. Its now working. I've got a backup of complete file so incase if in future I need it, I can use that. anyways thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Datamapper doesn't include a helper called datamapper_helper.

So either you've used a third party product in your application or you're not using an official Datamapper version.

Comment: I just copied all the files of DATAMAPPER in CODEIGNITER. If this is not the proper solution then how should I overcome from this problem. any help is much appreciated. I want a proper solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In the file "autoload.php" should be defined something like:

```
$ autoload ['helper'] = array (.... something ....., 'DataMapper');
```

put it better in the following way:

```
$ autoload ['helper'] = array ('url');
```

or somewhere you put your controller:

```
$ this-> load-> helper (array (... something ....., 'form', 'DataMapper'));
```

put it better in the following way:

```
$ this-> load-> helper (array (... something ....., 'form'));
```

ie remove the word 'DataMapper' and again revizar your settings as:
http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/installation.html